# $_FILES does not contain form file input

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I am performing a simple form upload that includes file upload

This is the html code:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" enctype="    multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group col-xs-8">
         <label for="image">image</label>
         <input type="file" class="form-control"  id="image" name="image" required="">
 </div>

<div class="form-group col-xs-8">
       <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success" id="subm" name="submit_e"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> ADD</button>
 </div>
```

The PHP code:

```
include('dbconnect.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit_e'])){

        $image_name=$_FILES['image']['name'];
        $folder="uploads/";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $folder.$_FILES['image']['name']);

$query="INSERT INTO products(folder,image_name) VALUES ('$folder','$image_name');
$exec=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

I am getting this error on the browser:
    **Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp2\htdocs\ecommerce\admin\index.php on line 13**

What am I missing there?

Comment: I don't see your form closing.

Comment: If you add this to the php code, echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_FILES);
echo '</pre>'; what does it show as being in the $_FILES array?

Comment: Remove spaces here: enctype="    multipart/form-data"

Comment: @piyush I included it still notworking

Comment: @SpacePhoenix That worked perfectly. I removed the space now everything is all fine. Thank you.